# Insert data into MySQL database from inputs that are not empty with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have page where user can update or change his profile information for example his location or his profile picture. By default every user get placeholder data or information on his profile page and those fields in mysql database are empty or row with that user id doesn't exists. So first i am checking if user previously entered his profile information into database and if data exist i will just update it with input fields that are not empty and this part works. But if data doesn't exists in database or row with this user id doesn't exist then i want to insert data but again only with **inputs that are not empty**.

But this is error i am getting

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;...

This is my code (`$userID` is session `$userID = $_SESSION['ID'];`)

```
if(isset($_POST['updateInfo'])) {
$userDesc = filter_var($_POST['description_update'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$userLocation = filter_var($_POST['location_update'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$userBirthDate = filter_var($_POST['birthDate_update'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_picture_tmp = $_FILES['user_picture']['tmp_name'];
$user_picture_name = $_FILES['user_picture']['name'];


$checkInfo = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userid=:userID");
$checkInfo->execute(array(':userID' => $userID));
$data = $checkInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
$count_rows = $checkInfo->rowCount();

//Here i am checking if data exists in mysql and UPDATING it    
if($count_rows > 0) {   

    if(!empty($userDesc)) {
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_info SET description=:description WHERE userid=:userID");
        $query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':description'=> $userDesc));
    }   
    if(!empty($userLocation)) {
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_info SET location=:location WHERE userid=:userID");
        $query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':location'=> $userLocation));
    }
    if(!empty($userBirthDate)) {
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_info SET birthDate=:birthDate WHERE userid=:userID");
        $query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':birthDate'=> $userBirthDate));
    }
    if(!empty($user_picture_name)) {
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE user_info SET profile_pic=:profile_pic WHERE userid=:userID");
        move_uploaded_file($user_picture_tmp, 'user_pic/'.$user_picture_name);
        $query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':profile_pic'=> $user_picture_name));

    }   
    //But if data doesn't exists i want to INSERT IT and here is error
}   else {

    if($userDesc AND $userLocation AND $userBirthDate AND $user_picture_name != '') {

        $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(userid) VALUES(:userID)");
        $query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID));

        if(!empty($userDesc)) {
            $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(description) VALUES(?) WHERE userid=?");
            $query->execute(array($userDesc, $userID));
        }   
        if(!empty($userLocation)) {
            $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(location) VALUES(?) WHERE userid=?");
            $query->execute(array($userLocation, $userID));
        }
        if(!empty($userBirthDate)) {
            $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(birthDate) VALUES(?) WHERE userid=?");
            $query->execute(array($userBirthDate, $userID));
        }   
        if(!empty($user_picture_name)) {
            $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(profile_pic) VALUES(?) WHERE userid=?");
            move_uploaded_file($user_picture_tmp, 'user_pic/'.$user_picture_name);
            $query->execute(array($user_picture_name, $userID));

        }
    } else {echo 'All fields are empty';} 

}                       
}
```

So my question is why am i getting this error and also am i doing this the wrong way or is there some other better approach to do this. 
This is just for learning purposes.

Comment: There is  no "insert into ... where ..." syntax. You have to use "update ..."

Comment: You are right. But its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a lot of inserts there! You should only do one insert!

Try replacing your else-statement with the following:

```
else {
    if($userDesc AND $userLocation AND $userBirthDate AND $user_picture_name != '') {

        if($userDesc = ''){$userDesc = 'Placeholder description';}
        if($userLocation = ''){$userLocation = 'Placeholder location';}
        if($userBirthDate = ''){$userBirthDate = 'Placeholder birthdate';}
        if($user_picture_name = ''){$user_picture_name = 'Placeholder picture_name';}

        if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(description, location, birthDate, profile_pic ) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $userDesc, $userLocation,$userBirthDate, $user_picture_name );
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    } else {echo 'All fields are empty';} 
}
```

Comment: Yea but the point is if the input is empty i don't want to enter that instead i want to keep placeholder data.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code so that you can add placeholder data if the fields are empty.